# Assign a row class like "row-1" for row 1, "row-2" for row 2

Tags: 8, views

I have a view that uses the Table format.

I want to add row classes like this:

- Row 1: `.row1`
- Row 2: `.row2`
- Row 3: `.row3`

In the Views UI, if I click *Settings* under **Format: Table**, then I can specify the **Row class**.  This field allows tokens, but I can't find a token that refers to the views row itself.

How can I implement a row class that assigns a number based on the position of the row in the view?

Comment: @NoSssweat Yes, that's what I wanted to ask. Let's close this as a dupe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are plenty of ways to go about this question, my suggestion is [overriding twig templates](https://befused.com/drupal/twig-debug).

You would need to override the Twig template for that view. If you [enable debug](https://www.drupal.org/docs/theming-drupal/twig-in-drupal/debugging-twig-templates), clear cache, inspect element, you will see the template for that view. Then for that twig file, just use the loop index

```
loop.index  The current iteration of the loop. (1 indexed)
```

to track which row you are in.